# TreeModelSort not working with TreeModelFilter

Tags: sorting, gtk, vala

I would like to have a TreeView on which filter as well as sorting works. However I can either make filter work or sorting work but not both.

The following is my code snippet on which filter works but not sorting when I click on the column header

```
portsTreeModelFilter = new Gtk.TreeModelFilter (myListStore);
portsTreeModelFilter.set_visible_func(filterTree);
ports_tcp_table_treeview.set_model(portsTreeModelFilter);
Gtk.TreeModelSort portsTreeModelSort = new TreeModelSort.with_model (portsTreeModelFilter);
portsTreeModelSort.set_sort_column_id(4,SortType.DESCENDING);
```

Here is the filter function

```
private bool filterTree (TreeModel model, TreeIter iter){
    bool isFilterCriteriaMatch = true;
    //If there is nothing to filter then make the data visible
    if (headerSearchBar.get_text() == ""){
            isFilterCriteriaMatch = true;
    }else{      
        string searchValueString = "";
        GLib.Value searchValue;
        int noOfColumns = model.get_n_columns();
        for (int count = 0; count < noOfColumns; count++){
            model.get_value (iter, count, out searchValue);
            searchValueString = searchValue.get_string();        
            if (searchValueString.index_of(headerSearchBar.get_text()) > -1){
                isFilterCriteriaMatch = true;
                break;
            }else{
                isFilterCriteriaMatch =  false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isFilterCriteriaMatch;
}
```

And this is how the filter function is called when the user types in the headersearch bar:

```
headerSearchBar.search_changed.connect (() => {
        portsTreeModelFilter.refilter ();
});
```

Appreciate any pointers on what needs to be done for sorting to work on click of column header.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it not work? What's your `filterTree` function?

Comment: @andlabs aded my filtertree function to the question above, which works nicely with filtering the rows as I type. When I click on the column headers for the sorting the headers blink but the rows donot sort. If I remove the treemodelfilter the sorting works.

Comment: Resolved the issue. I was not chaining the filer and sort properly. Here is the code in Vala for anyone struggling with the same:
aTreeModelFilter = new Gtk.TreeModelFilter (myListStore, null);
aTreeModelFilter.set_visible_func(myFilterFunction);
Gtk.TreeModelSort aTreeModelSort = new TreeModelSort.with_model (aTreeModelFilter);
aTreeview.set_model(aTreeModelSort);
aTreeview.get_column(0).set_sort_column_id(0);